# Non-delimited parameters in function

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, function-parameter

I've just found a [script for progress bars](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3152162#3152162) for Photoshop UI
the function is set up as a variable in the following form, which I've not seen before.

```
var ProgressBar = function(/*str*/title)
```

- Firstly why are the two parameters not separated by a comma? as in:

  ```
  var ProgressBar = function(str, title)
  ```
- Secondly what is the significance of /* */ around the string parameter?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think this is because of wrong type of comment practice follow. It might indicate that title is required which will be type of  string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of wrong type of comment practice follow. It indicates that title is required which will be type of  string. As you can see in provided link

```
 var pBar = new ProgressBar("Script Title");
```

provided  input is string type.